# Merging two images of different size with rotate and zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, merge, uiimage, cgcontext

I'm facing the following problem : I have to merge two images bottomImg and topImg to create a new image C as a result of the merging.
I already know how to merge two images but in this case my goal is a little bit different.
top image may be zoomed and rotated.

I have follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6984008/4831567). But in this solution top image is cut while i rotate. simulator [image]

actual stored image is document like [image]

I have try this code

_parentViewGIf for bottomImg and for _ivGIF for topImg

```
- (UIImage *)mergeImage:(UIImage *)bottomImg withImage:(UIImage *)topImg {


    float width=bottomImg.size.width*_ivGIF.frame.size.width/_parentViewGIf.frame.size.width;
    float height=bottomImg.size.width*_ivGIF.frame.size.height/_parentViewGIf.frame.size.width;

    UIImage * scaledTopImg = [self imageByScalingProportionallyWithImage:topImg ToSize:CGSizeMake(bottomImg.size.width, bottomImg.size.height)];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(scaledTopImg.size);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, scaledTopImg.size.height * 0.5, scaledTopImg.size.height * 0.5);
    CGFloat angle = atan2(_ivGIF.transform.a, _ivGIF.transform.b);
    CGContextRotateCTM(ctx, angle);
    [scaledTopImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(- scaledTopImg.size.width * 0.5f, -(scaledTopImg.size.height  * 0.5f), scaledTopImg.size.width , scaledTopImg.size.height )];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    float x=bottomImg.size.width*_ivGIF.frame.origin.x/_parentViewGIf.frame.size.width;
    float y=bottomImg.size.width*_ivGIF.frame.origin.y/_parentViewGIf.frame.size.width;


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bottomImg.size);
    [bottomImg drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, bottomImg.size.width, bottomImg.size.height)];
    [newImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newImage.size.width, newImage.size.height)];
    UIImage *newImage2 = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage2;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestion

Comment: Zoom it to fit. Use line segments intersection to figure out the right scale.

Comment: @Andy sorry i can't understand what you say.

Comment: can you specify which actual result image you want.

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya i want image like simulator(1st image)

Comment: Yes but if topImage is zoom and rotated then ..?? i think you want result like 2nd image. right?

Comment: @MiteshDobareeya no i don't want 2nd image as result but i want result like 1st image(same to simulator's image). in 2nd image top image is zoom after merge.